# Howto deploy a Github fork of a CKAN-plugin?

Tags: python, github, ckan

I'm localizing the [ckan archiver plugin](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-archiver) for additional languages.

For testing puropses I'd like to

- fork the Github repo
- make and test my changes locally
- update my forked Github repo and use it with multiple customer installations
- make a Github pull request to integrate my changes to the official repo

My question: How to tell CKAN to use my forked Github repo?

Is this possible in the plugin spec `ckan.ini`:

```
[app:main]
ckan.plugins = stats text_view recline_view archiver # old
ckan.plugins = stats text_view recline_view mygithubaccount/myarchiverfork # new?
```

or how can this be achieved instead?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the virtual environment, you need to install your fork:

1. . /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
2. git clone your forked_repo
3. cd forked_repo && python setup.py develop

Then just use the same name inside the ckan.plugins